# Multiples of an equivalence class

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**Definition:**
For any $[x]$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}/n$ and any $k$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$, we can define $k[x]$ by
$k[x]  =  [x] + [x] + \ldots  +[x]$ (i.e. $[x]$ is added $k$ times) where the result is an element of $\mathbb{Z}/n$. We say $k[x]$ is a multiple of $[x]$.

Having this definition in mind, list all the multiples of $[3]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/8$. I know that the answer is all the equivalence classes between $0$ and $8$ (i.e. $[0], [1], \ldots , [7]$). I can't quite figure out why this is though.

I understand why $[0], [3], [6]$ would be multiples of $[3]$ (since $0, 3,$ and $6$ are multiples of $3$), but why can the rest of the equivalence classes ($[1], [2], [4],$ etc.) be included as multiples? The numbers inside these equivalence classes are not multiples of $3$ and the elements inside these classes are also not multiples of the elements in $[3]$ (i.e. {..., 2, 10, 18, ...} are not multiples of {..., 3, 11, 19,...}). Why then can all the classes between $[0]$ and $[7]$ be included as multiples of $[3]$?

The multiples of $[3]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/9$, on the other hand, are just $[0], [3],$ and $[6]$. Do the multiples of an equivalence class $[x]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n$ only equal to $[k \cdot x]$ if $x$ itself is a multiple of $n$? What if $x$ is not a multiple of $n$?

Comment: All you need to know is that $[3] \times 3 = [9] = [1].$

Comment: How can I justify the other classes also being multiples though?

Comment: Notice that everything is a multiple of $1$...

Comment: Aren't we checking for multiples of 3 though? And why would the case be different for $[3]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/9$? Is it because in the second case 9 actually a multiple of 3?

Comment: Firstly, if everything is a multiple of 1, and 1 is a multiple of 3... Second, correct.

Comment: I agree. So if I understand correctly, if $[x]$ is a multiple of $n$, you would just include classes whose representatives are multiples of $x$ (i.e. the $[k \cdot x]$ classes) and if $[x]$ is not a multiple of $n$, then you include all classes because you're only worried about their representatives being multiples of one?

Comment: Its not explicitly because $9$ is a multiple of three, but rather because $9$ *is not coprime to $3$*.  If you were to run the same exercise in $\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$ with the equivalence class $[6]$ the same thing will happen as it did with $[3]$ despite $9$ not being a multiple of $6$.  Essentially, it is asking you to find the [subgroup generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) by $[3]$

Comment: How can you justify [6] is a multiple of 3.  8+6 =14 $\in $ [6] but 14 is not a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it.

$1 [3]=[3]$

$2 [3]=[6]$

$3 [3]=[9=8+1]=[1] $

$4 [3]=[12=8+4]=[4]$

$5 [3]=[15=8+7]=[7]$

$6 [3]=[18=2*8+2]=[2] $

$7 [3]=[21=2*8+5]=[5] $

$8 [3]=[24=3*+0]=[0] $.

===

Okay... the thing is $[x] $ is not just $x $ it is the entire set $\{x+8k\} $.

So $ [1]= \{1,9,17,25,33,41..\} $ and $[1]=[9]=[17] ... etc.$.

It doesn't matter if you use $x $ to show the class or if you use some other $x+8k $.  Some will be multiples of $3$ (such as $9,33, $ or any $9\pm24k $) and some will not.  So long as *one* of the terms is a multiple of three the class *represents* that number (and all others).

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to do the same for the equivalence classes of $[3]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/9$ to eventually include $[0], [1], \ldots, [8]$?

Comment: No.  Because 9 is a different number than 8.

Comment: What you will discover as you study these, is the the multiples of x in Z_m will be the multiples of gcd (x,m) as gcd (8,3)=1.  All classes are multiples 3 in Z_8.  But the multiples of [4] are  [4], and [0].  In Z_9 the multiples of [3] are [3], [6],and [0] but all are multiples of [4],  i.e. [4], [8], [12=3][16 =7][20=2][24=6][28=1][32=5][36=0]

Comment: Take the multiples of 9 in 15.  They are [9],[9+9=18=3], [3+9=12][12+9=21=6][6+9=15=0] $.  Do you see the pattern?